# обновить записи в базе mysql

Tags: php

Всем доброе утро, возник вопрос, как обновить в базе n-количество записей которые выводятся на экран в окнах input?

```
if(isset($_POST['add_upd'])){

        $title_upd = $_POST['title_upd'];
        $data_upd = $_POST['data_upd'];
    $update = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE rash SET month='$title_upd',
    summa='$data_upd'");
    header("Location:update.php?add=".$_GET['add']);


}
```

этот код обновляет все записи под под последнюю в базе

Answer (score 1):

Не "под последнюю в базе", а "под" те данные, которые ты передаёшь в запрос.

Обновить в базе n-количество записей которые выводятся на экран в окнах input точно так же, как и одну запись. Только в цикле. Для этого надо сначала в учебнике прочитать, как выполнять запросы UPDATE, потом прочитать в учебнике, как пользоваться циклами, и после этого в форме для "окон input" задать атрибут name в виде

```
name="update[1]"
```

где 1 - уникальный идентификатор строки в базе.

Плюс к этому, ты должен передавать данные в запрос через плейсхолдер, а не напрямую. Поэтому осваивай PDO

Comment: протом прочесть в учебнике как нажать на кнопку и какую силу G приложить что бы включить комп, конкретное что то есть хотя бы на данном примере?

Comment: Да. Вам же сказали - загляните в учебник, даже в какие именно разделы.

Comment: если нечего по существу то не бороздите лохматого, куда заглянуть и что прочитать я могу и без ВАШИХ советов, сюда люди не для этого обращаются

Comment: Очевидно сюда люди обращаются только чтобы скопировать кусок кода так ничему и не научившись. Простите за прямоту. Ответ дан по существу, жаль, если вам он не пригодился.

Comment: люди обращаются именно за куском кода, ибо если человек знает он отвечает если нет, не стоит делать вид что ты зашкаливающий специалист знаешь что и где написано

Comment: Заплатите кому-нибудь за курсовую. Других шансов у вас нет.

Answer (score 0):

Попробую и я только своими словами:

1. UPDATE строки всегда (!!!) должен сопровождаться условием WHERE. Обычно там упоминается id записи.
2. В вашей форме должна быть информация, которую обработчик формы использует в этом условии. То есть указание этого id.

Это правило справедливо для любой формы и любой таблицы в базе. Для нескольких строк вам понадобится несколько вызовов UPDATE с разными данными и разными id в условии. Логично использовать цикл, а в имени инпутов использовать эти id.

Comment: загнал кнопку добавить в базу в циквл и форме в action добавил id и все работает, да пускай пускай под каждым инпутом кнопка но работает

Comment: Зачем так мучаться! id можно поместить в имя инпута, в квадратных скобках, как *Ипатьев* подсказал: <input name="title_upd[112]"…>. Затем по всем значениям можно пройтись циклом foreach($_POST['title_upd'] as $id => $title)

Comment: надо будет попробовать